# Retrofit + Gson convertor json RFC7159 support

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

In my application I am using retrofit with Gson converter. Below are the gradles.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

From Magento2 backend am getting response in json format. Here JSON standard is RFC7159. It is not supported by Gson. Like in response am getting following values only

Response 1 : "some string", 
Response 2 : true

Gson is not able to read these kind of values. What changes I need to do in order to read these values or support RFC7159 standard. Please suggest.

Comment: which version of GSON u use?

Comment: if you use version older than 2.6.1 than I can post a solution that ll work

Answer (score 0):

GSON version of 2.6.1 and newer started to support RFC7159, just update your dependency in gradle to this:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

And, please, dont forget to delete old/prev version